# Как сделать вот такой слайдер?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, вёрстка

как можно реализовать такой слайдер?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://bkosborne.com/jquery-waterwheel-carousel

Comment: данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)

Answer (score 0):

Вот сайт с примерами реализаций похожих слайдеров.
https://itchief.ru/javascript/slider-on-css-and-javascript